# Searching bing results with a script results in an encoding issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, bing

I've written the following in order to get number of search results per word in my `wordlist`:

```
with open ("C:\wordslist.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

def bingSearch(word):   
    r = requests.get('http://www.bing.com/search',
                 params={'q':'"'+word+'"'}
                )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    return (soup.find('span',{'class':'sb_count'}))

matches = [re.search(regex,line).groups() for line in lines]
for match in matches:       
    searchWord = match[0]
    found = bingSearch(searchWord)
    print (found.text)
```

It works well and I get accurate results, except for words containing special characters, for example the word: `"número"`.

If I call `bingSearch("número")` I get an accurate result. 
If I call `bingSearch(match[0])` (where printing `match[0]` yields `"número"`) I get an inaccurate result.

I've tried stuff like `str(match[0])`, `match[0].encode(encoding="UTF-8")`, but with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting what's going over the wire? That is, have you tried using some network sniffing tool or a trace tool, or anything that will show you what the outgoing HTTP GET request looks like?   Seems like you need to debug your bingSearch function internals and not just randomly try external things.  Also you need to specify more than "no success". You get no results or you get results you can't match to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try giving the encoding directly when you open your file, it can make the difference

`with open ("C:\wordslist.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open